# I want to add a generic element to this linked list in an ordered way

Tags: java

```
public void add(T element)
{
    
    
    LinearNode<T>previous=head;
    LinearNode<T>current=head.getNext();
    LinearNode<T>node= new LinearNode<>();

    
    if(!(element instanceof Comparable))
    {
        throw new NonComparableElementException("OrderList");
    }

    Comparable<T>comparableElement= (Comparable<T>)element;

    if(comparableElement.compareTo(head.getElement())<0)
    {
        head=node;
    }
    else
    {
        while(current!=null && comparableElement.compareTo(current.getElement())>0)
        {
            previous=current;
            current=current.getNext();
        }
        previous.setNext(node);
    }
    count++;
}
```

I have been trying to write this add method which adds the specified element to this list at the location determined by the element's natural ordering but it gives an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jsjf.LinearNode.getNext()" because "this.head" is null
        at jsjf.LinkedOrderedList.add(LinkedOrderedList.java:36)
        at jsjf.LinkedListTester.main(LinkedListTester.java:8)
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a clear or valid explanation of behavior. What *does* it do? What are you expecting it to do? Can you give example output of what it does vs what you're expecting it to do? Are you receiving any errors? If so what are they?

Comment: Also please [edit] your question to include sample input and expected and current output. See [ask].

Comment: You need to handle `null` here: `LinearNode<T>current=head.getNext();`

Answer (score 1):

As for the error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot
> invoke "jsjf.LinearNode.getNext()" because "this.head" is null at
> jsjf.LinkedOrderedList.add(LinkedOrderedList.java:36) at
> jsjf.LinkedListTester.main(LinkedListTester.java:8)
> ```

The error is due to line 4:

> ```
> LinearNode<T>current=head.getNext();
> ```

You should do a null check before accessing the head's contents. If the head is null, then simply insert at head:

```
if (head == null) {
    head = comparableElement;
    return;
}
```

---

**Explanation**:

There are four cases you need to consider when adding an element to an [ordered LinkedList](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-a-linked-list-in-java-using-class/):

1. When insertion happens at the beggining (you covered this case).
2. When insertion happens to an empty LinkedList.
3. When insertion happens at the end of the list (you covered this case).
4. When insertion happens in the middle of the list.

I've edited your code and made the necessary additions for it to work:

```
public void add(T element) {
    // Create new node and store data in it
    LinearNode<T> comparableElement = new LinearNode<>(element);
    LinearNode<T> prev = null, curr = head;

    if (!(element instanceof Comparable)) {
        throw new NonComparableElementException("OrderList");
    }

    // Decide where to add new node in LinkedList
    while (curr != null && curr.getData().compareTo(comparableElement.getData()) < 0) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.getNext();
    }

    // Add node in LinkedList
    if (head == null) {  // Case 0: Empty LinkedList
        head = comparableElement;
    } else if (prev == null) {   // Case 1: Insert at beginning
        comparableElement.setNext(head);
        head = comparableElement;
    } else if (curr != null) {  // Case 2: Insert in between
        prev.setNext(comparableElement);
        comparableElement.setNext(curr);
    } else // Case 3: Insert at the end
        prev.setNext(comparableElement);

    count++;
}
```

What the code essentially does is it loops to the correct insertion position and manipulates the pointers accordingly to insert the item.